# Why do some (many?) Youtube videos not play?

Tags: video, youtube

Very often when I click on an embedded Youtube video or even access a Youtube video though the Youtube app, I get an error that curtly says "This video cannot be played". What gives?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a flag that people can set on their YouTube videos to allow or disallow those videos to be played on a mobile device. What you are seeing when you try to access those videos is that the person has set the flag to 'Disallow'.

Comment: Typically producers of popular music disallow their content to be played on mobile phones.

Comment: Is this flag set to disallow by default?

Comment: @S Red - It didn't used to be. I haven't uploaded a video in awhile, though, so I don't know. What videos are you trying to watch? As @Bryan pointed out, things like music videos aren't typically allowed on phones.